# Adding edge caching for GCE

Tags: caching, cdn, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to add some caching for our Compute Engine server using cache-control and max-age, but I don't see any caching happening. 
From the description here - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFbfULXoXn8&feature=share&t=2m1s it should work seamlessly.

Looks like only GCS and GAE are supported. Or am I missing something?
It would be really, really great to have support for edge caching in GCE as well

Comment: I'm not sure the video is talking on GCE... only GAE.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Caching will be a great addition GCE as well

Answer (score 2):

As more in the comments, GCE doors not provide a CDN or edge caching solution with the layer 3/layer 4 load balancer.  Using cache-control and max-age will still allow other intermediate proxies (e.g. ISP or mobile network caches) to cache your content.

At the moment, the best solution I can think of if you need edge caching is to hire one of the companies that specializes in this, such as Akamai.  You can then point Akamai at your load-balanced GCE IP address as the content source, the same way you would with an on-premise server.

Sorry I can't point you to a more-integrated solution right now; since this is supported on GAE, I have to imagine that the GCE networking team is aware of the interest.